# How to create a TargetDataLine using a binary array WebSocket?

Tags: java, websocket, arrays, audio-processing

I've created a byte array WebSocket that receives audio chunks in real time from the client's mic ([navigator.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)). I'm already recording this stream to a WAV file in the server, after some time that the WebSocket stops to receive new byte arrays. The following code represents the current situation.

WebSocket

```
@OnMessage
public void message(byte[] b) throws IOException{
    if(byteOutputStream == null) {
        byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byteOutputStream.write(b);
    } else {
        byteOutputStream.write(b);
    }
}
```

Thread that stores the WAV file

```
public void store(){
    byte b[] = byteOutputStream.toByteArray();
    try {
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, true);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(byteStream, audioFormat, b.length);
        DateTime date = new DateTime();
        File file = new File("/tmp/"+date.getMillis()+ ".wav");
        AudioSystem.write(audioStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);
        audioStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But instead of record a WAV file, my goal with this WebSocket is to process audio in real time using [YIN pitch detection algorithm](http://0110.be/releases/TarsosDSP/TarsosDSP-latest/TarsosDSP-latest-Documentation/be/tarsos/dsp/pitch/Yin.html) implemented on [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) library. In other words, this is basically execute the [PitchDetectorExample](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/examples/be/tarsos/dsp/example/PitchDetectorExample.java), but using the data  from the WebSocket instead of the Default Audio Device (OS mic). The following code represents how [PitchDetectorExample](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/examples/be/tarsos/dsp/example/PitchDetectorExample.java) is currently initializing live audio processing using the mic line provided by the OS.

```
private void setNewMixer(Mixer mixer) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {      
    if(dispatcher!= null){
        dispatcher.stop();
    }
    currentMixer = mixer;
    float sampleRate = 44100;
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int overlap = 0;
    final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, true);
    final DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    TargetDataLine line;
    line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    final int numberOfSamples = bufferSize;
    line.open(format, numberOfSamples);
    line.start();
    final AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(line);
    JVMAudioInputStream audioStream = new JVMAudioInputStream(stream);
    // create a new dispatcher
    dispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(audioStream, bufferSize, overlap);
    // add a processor
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new PitchProcessor(algo, sampleRate, bufferSize, this));
    new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio dispatching").start();
}
```

There is a way to deal with WebSocket data as a TargetDataLine, so it will be possible to hook it up with [AudioDispatcher](http://0110.be/releases/TarsosDSP/TarsosDSP-latest/TarsosDSP-latest-Documentation/be/tarsos/dsp/AudioDispatcher.html) and [PitchProcessor](http://0110.be/releases/TarsosDSP/TarsosDSP-latest/TarsosDSP-latest-Documentation/be/tarsos/dsp/pitch/PitchProcessor.html)? Somehow, i need to send the byte arrays received from the WebSocket to the audio processing Thread.

Another ideas on how reach this objective are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need an audioDispatcher. If you know how the bytes are encoded (PCM, 16bits le mono?) then you can convert them to floating points real-time and feed them to the pitchdetector algorithm, in your websocket you can do something like this (and forget about the inputstreams and audiodispatcher):

```
 int index;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
 float[] floatBuffer = new float[1024];
 FastYin detector = new FastYin(44100,1024);
 public void message(byte[] b){
   for(int i = 0 ; i < b.length; i++){
     buffer[index] = b[i];
     index++
     if(index==2048){
       AudioFloatConverter converter = AudioFloatConverter.getConverter(new Format(16bits, little endian, mono,...));
       //converts the byte buffer to float
       converter.toFloatArray(buffer,floatBuffer);
       float pitch = detector.getPitch(floatBuffer);
       //here you have your pitch info that you can use
       index = 0;
     }
   }
```

You do need to watch the number of bytes that have passed: since two bytes represent one float (if 16bits pcm encoding is used) you need to start on even bytes. The endianness and samplerate are also important.

Regards

Joren

Comment: Besides the fact that i forgot to express my gratitude some months ago, your advise saved my project and i was able to move on extracting all the information i needed from the audio signal. Just a quick feedback is that i had to use TarsosDSPAudioFloatConverter instead of AudioFloatConverter that you suggested, also the detector.getPitch method returns a PitchDetectionResult object instead a float. Im not sure if this is because of the version of TarsosDSP lib im using (2.3) but it was a success anyway. Thank you very much Joren and congrats for this amazing DSP solution you created! :)